# How to make urlrewrite (tuckey) ignore css and js requests and stop processing other rules?

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a urlrewrite.xml file with several rules in it.  I'd like to put a rule at the very beginning to match any/all css or js requests and just pass them through AND STOP COMPARING TO ANY OTHER RULES...

I've got this:

```
<rule>
   <name>RULE: ignore js and css</name>
    <from>^(.*(\.css|\.js))$</from>
    <to last="true">$1</to>
</rule>
```

but it seems this just causes the whole thing to loop repeatedly.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer...posting it here for future searchers...

I just had to change the "to" part.  Instead of using $1 I found a reference to using the dash '-' so I gave it a try and it worked...

```
<rule>
   <name>RULE: ignore js and css</name>
    <from>^(.*(\.css|\.js))$</from>
    <to last="true">-</to>
</rule>
```